Checking the database connection with pg-promise
My project has two databases, one read/write and the other read only.
When making a select request, I need to check if the second database is available.
Function that does the check
const getDb = () => {
  dbR
    .connect()
    .then(() => {
      return dbR;
    })
    .catch(() => {
      return dbRW;
    });
};

I call like this
await getDb().oneOrNone(sql);

But i get it

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'oneOrNone' of undefined

Most likely I am using the return operator incorrectly in the promise.

Well getDb itself does not return anything, it only builds a promise chain.

how can i return a promise?

Your code leaks connection. See Verify database connection with pg-promise

Btw, even when you return the promise, you'd need to use it as await (await getDb()).oneOrNone(sql)

getDb doesn't return anything explicitly, so it implicitly returns undefined, causing the error that you see.
You can either return the promise references there explicitly:
const getDb = () => {
  return dbR // Here!
    .connect()
    .then(() => {
      return dbR;
    })
    .catch(() => {
      return dbRW;
    });
};

or remove the curly braces so it becomes an arrow function with an expression (which is returned) instead of a series of statements (which requires an explicit return):
const getDb = () => // No curly braces!
  dbR
    .connect()
    .then(() => {
      return dbR;
    })
    .catch(() => {
      return dbRW;
    });

The same can be done, of course, with the arrow function in the then and catch calls. This shouldn't have any functional impact (since these functions already properly return their expected values), but it could arguably clean up the code:
const getDb = () => // No curly braces!
  dbR
    .connect()
    .then(() => dbR)
    .catch(() => dbRW);


From the promises view, this answer is correct. But from the database view, such code will leak connections, as it does in the question. The author of the question misuses connect method.
